# Unable to init from given binary data using docker container

Tags: php, laravel

Unable to init from given binary data.

I want to save an image with laravel using Vue.js
but, As I wrote in the title, An error is returned
「Unable to init from given binary data.」
In laravel I write the code as follows

```
$image = $request->get('imgUrl1');
$name = time().'.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($image, 0, strpos($image, ';')))[1])[1];
$base=base64_decode($image);
Image::make($base)->save(public_path('img/articles/').$name);



imgUrl1: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfcA...
<string is too large to edit>
```

Unable to init from given binary data.

```
"message": "Unable to init from given binary data.",
    "exception": "Intervention\\Image\\Exception\\NotReadableException",
    "file": "/var/www/laravel/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Gd/Decoder.php",
    "line": 113,
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to use the full content of the url including the data:image header. You can try manually stripping the data:image/png... from the string using regular expression or simply use file_get_contents($image) which should return the decoded image and then just pass it to the make method

```
$imageData = file_get_contents($request->get('imgUrl1'));
$image = Image::make($imageData);
$image->save();
```

Comment: It went well ! Thanks to your help, I can proceed with your work. Thank you very much